# Issue with AJAX URL for file

Tags: ajax, xml, file, url

having as issue with my url in my AJAX script. I need the file data.xml to be loaded but unsure of how to attach it. The current code isn't working.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.xml",    <--- issue here
    dataType: "xml",
```

Here is what my folder structure looks like. I need to attach data.xml to update.js

```
Website
├── app.py
├── data2.xml
├── data.xml  <-- File that needs to be attached
├── Dockerfile
├── __pycache__
│   ├── Crypto.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── lxml.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── ScprAG.cpython-38.pyc
│   └── scraper.cpython-38.pyc
├── requirements.txt
├── scraper.py
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── 404.css
│   │   └── main.css
│   ├── images
│   │   └── favicon.png
│   └── js
│       ├── plugin.js
│       └── update.js   <-- AJAX Script
└── templates
    ├── 404.html
    ├── disclaimer.html
    ├── index.html
    └── layout.html
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a forward slash before the filename, like this: `url: "/data.xml"`? Your .js file is not in the root directory, so it is looking for the file in the same directory where update.js lives.

Comment: It seems like I had to render the xml file as its own webpage and then link it. Will give your suggestion a go. Is my alternative safe for in production situations?

Comment: Normally, data in a web app is generated from a database or fetched from a third-party API. If your .xml file data is static, saving it in the root folder will mean that it is readable via a typed-in URL, but it will not be writable as long as the permissions on the folder and file are set correctly on the production server.

Comment: Moved it into the templates folder for now. Thanks for the tip